# Perl - Mechanize object size too big

Tags: perl, www-mechanize, chunks

i am trying to get a xml file from a database using WWW::Mechanize. I know that the file is quite big (bigger than my memory) and it is constantly crashes either i try to view it in the browser or try to store in in a file using get(). I am planning to user XML::Twig in the future, but i cannot ever store the result in a file.

Does anyone know how to split the mechanized object in little chunks,get them one after another, and store them in a file, one after another without running out of memory?

Here is the query api: [ArrayExpress Programmatic Access](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/help/programmatic_access.html) .

Thank you.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $base = 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/xml/v2/experiments';
#Parameters
my $query ='?species="homo sapiens"' ;
my $url = $base . $query;

# Create a new mechanize object
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(stack_depth=>0);

# Associate the mechanize object with a URL
$mech->get($url);

#store xml content
my $content = $mech->content;

#open output file for writing
unlink("ArrayExpress_Human_Final.txt");
open( $fh, '>>:encoding(UTF-8)','ArrayExpress_Human_Final.txt') || die "Can't open file!\n";
print $fh $content;
close $fh;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like what you want to do is save the file directly to disk, rather than loading it into memory.

From the [Mech FAQ](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize/FAQ.pod#How_do_I_save_an_image?_How_do_I_save_a_large_tarball?) question "How do I save an image? How do I save a large tarball?"

> You can also save any content directly to disk using the :content_file flag to get(), which is part of LWP::UserAgent.

```
$mech->get( 'http://www.cpan.org/src/stable.tar.gz',
            ':content_file' => 'stable.tar.gz' );
```

Also note that if all you're doing is downloading the file, it may not even make sense to use WWW::Mechanize, and to use the underlying LWP::UserAgent directly.